# Cannot install cartopy Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cartopy

I am trying to install cartopy package and I run the following (Jupyter Notebook, Macbook):

```
conda install -c conda-forge cartopy
```

while I get nothing but:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
```

If I try to run directly:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
```

the error shows up saying that such a module cannot be found. Any suggestions how to resolve the issue? I aslo tried to create new environment, did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to run first?

```
conda update conda
```

or

```
conda install conda-build
```